# Kivy: Display widgets on another screen through a function in python code

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to do what the title says. The problem that I'm running into is that everything happens successfully (like the widget gets added to the other screen) but for some reason it doesn't display it. Any ideas on why the widget is not displaying? I tried to search about updating the screen but I found no resource that could help.

Edit:

Here is some sample code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class Main(Screen):
    def button_clicked(self):
        sample_things = ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "bob"]
        second_screen_class = SecondScreen()
        second_screen_class.display_things(sample_things)


class SecondScreen(Screen):

    def display_things(self, stuff):
        layout = BoxLayout()
        ind = 0  # allows to add multiple widgets using a for loop

        for i in range(len(stuff)):
            layout.add_widget(Label(text=stuff[i]), index=ind)
            ind += 1

        self.ids.add_here.add_widget(layout)
        layout = BoxLayout()  # this is to prevent error if function is called again


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class SampleApp(App):
    pass


SampleApp().run()
```

Sample Kivy file:

```
ScreenManager:
    Main:
    SecondScreen:

<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "press me"
            on_press: root.button_clicked()
        Button:
            text: "next screen"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "SecondScreen"


<SecondScreen>:
    name: "SecondScreen"
    GridLayout:
        id: add_here
        cols: 2
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @John Anderson I added some code in the post